# Sending to Akka's Dead Letter Channel from many other actors in the fallback case

Tags: scala, akka

New to both Scala + Akka here. I have a small network of actors that all send different messages to each other. Many of them need access to my `DeadLetterChannel` actor in case they receive a message that they are not sure how to handle:

```
class DeadLetterChannel(val queue : mutable.Queue[Any]) extends Actor with Logging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case any : Any =>
      log.info(s"${this.getClass} just received a message of type ${} from ${sender().getClass}.")
      queue.enqueue(any)
    case _ =>
      log.warn(s"${this.getClass} just received a non-Any message.")
  }
}
```

Then from inside many other actors:

```
class DeviceManager(val dlc : DeadLetterChannel) extends ActorRef {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Heartbeat =>
      // Handle Heartbeat here...
    case Connect:
      // Handle Connect here...
    case Disconnect:
      // Handle Disconnect here...
    case _ =>
      dlc ! ???
  }
}
```

I have two problems here:

- I'm getting a compiler error on the sending of the message (specifically the `!` overload: "*Cannot resolve symbol !*"); and
- I have no idea what to send to `dlc` in the `_` case, any ideas? Obviously I'm just trying to send the message that `DeviceManager` received that is neither a `Heartbeat`, a `Connect` or a `Disconnect` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have over-simplified the code for your example, but you can't just send a message to an `Actor` class instance. You need to create a named actor using `actorOf` on an `ActorSystem`, and then use `actorSelection` on that system to get a handle on the actor.

For the second part of your question, just put a match value in the `case` and send the result:

```
case msg =>
  dlc ! msg
```

Also, you might want to use a different name for your class because a **dead letter** is message that *can't be delivered*, not a message that *can't be handled* by the recipient.

Comment: Thanks @Tim (+1) but wouldn't creating a new `DeadLetterChannel` instance (using `actorOf(...)`) inside each of my other actors create a **new child** DeadLetterChannel actor for all of them?! I think I want just *one* DLC actor that has the same parent as all my other actors.

Comment: Don't create it inside your actor, create a single instance of a `DeadLetterChannel` actor when you create all the other actors. Then you can use `ActorSelection` to locate that instance in each of your actors.

Answer (score 1):

Actor classes should extend `Actor` instead of `ActorRef`. Also, use `ActorRef` to reference an actor. `DeviceManager`, therefore, should be defined as the following:

```
class DeviceManager(dlc: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  // ...
}
```

The idea here is that you would use the `ActorRef` of the `DeadLetterChannel` actor when creating the device actors. For example:

```
val dlc: ActorRef = context.actorOf(/* .. */)
val device1: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[DeviceManager], dlc)
val device2: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[DeviceManager], dlc)
```

Then you can do as Tim suggested in his answer and capture the default case in the `receive` block and send this message to `dlc`:

```
class DeviceManager(dlc: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    /* other case clauses */
    case msg =>
      dlc ! msg
  }
}
```

Also, instead of passing a mutable queue to `DeadLetterChannel` as a constructor argument, encapsulate this state inside the actor as an immutable queue and expose it only via message passing:

```
class DeadLetterChannel extends Actor with akka.actor.ActorLogging {
  var queue = collection.immutable.Queue[Any](0)

  def receive = {
    case GetMessages => // GetMessages is a custom case object
      sender() ! queue
    case msg =>
      val s = sender()
      log.info(s"DLC just received the following message from [$s]: $msg")
      queue = queue.enqueue(msg)
  }
}
```

---

Another approach is to not define a default case (i.e., leave out the `case msg =>` clause) and use Akka's mechanisms for dealing with unhandled messages. Below are a couple of options:

1. Enable the [built-in logging for unhandled messages](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/logging.html#auxiliary-logging-options), which logs these messages at the DEBUG level:

   ```
   akka {
     actor {
       debug {
         # enable DEBUG logging of unhandled messages
         unhandled = on
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   This approach is perhaps the simplest if you just want to log unhandled messages.
2. As the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#actor-api) states:

   > If the current actor behavior does not match a received message...by default publishes an `akka.actor.UnhandledMessage(message, sender, recipient)` on the actor system’s event stream.

   In light of this, you could create an actor that subscribes to the event stream and handles [`akka.actor.UnhandledMessage`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/UnhandledMessage.html) messages. Such an actor could look like the following:

   ```
   import akka.actor.{ Actor, UnhandledMessage, Props }

   class UnhandledMessageListener extends Actor {
     def receive = {
       case UnhandledMessage(msg, sender, recipient) =>
         // do something with the message, such as log it and/or something else
     }
   }

   val listener = system.actorOf(Props[UnhandledMessageListener])
   system.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[UnhandledMessage])
   ```

   More information about the event stream and creating a subscriber to that stream can be found [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/event-bus.html#event-stream).